# Margin for the element are different in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, sass, margin

I have created a button on a card which margins works perfect with chrome but it changes in IE-11 when i test it. 
How can i write a CSS code that works for both browsers? Below i am attaching a snapshot of what i created and a code as well. it's the class ".btn-secondary" when i inspect it in IE and remove the "margin-top" it works.but then it messes up my chrome

[Screenshot of Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdcaD.png)

[screenshot of IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uajF.png)

```css
@import 'penske-colors';
@import 'typography';

.cap-header {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.card {
  margin-right: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.globe-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.selected-icon {
  fill: $gray-110-hex;
  display: inherit;
  width: 15.2px;
  height: 15.2px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.selected-type {
  border: 2px solid $rb-100-hsla;

  .btn-secondary{
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
    background: $gray-170-hex;
    color: $gray-80-hex;
    fill: $gray-80-hex;
  }
}

h5{
  margin-bottom: 10.5px;
}
.service-card {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  height: 136px;
  width: 258px;
}
.btn-secondary{
  margin: auto;  
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 36.27px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.service-desc {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.service-header {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.unit-type-card {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 164px;


  .btn-secondary{
    height: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h5 class="text-preset-5"
  [ngClass]="{ 'service-desc' : !isService }"
  *ngIf="capability?.description">{{ capability?.description }} </h5>
  <div interactive>
  <button type="button" class="text-preset-6 btn btn-secondary" >
    <app-inline-svg 
    *ngIf="isSelected" 
    class="selected-icon" 
    iconName="Check-circle-solid-empty" 
    size="20"></app-inline-svg>{{text}}</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: could you add all the html of you example (at last of the box) and related css?

Comment: Use a css reset, that will probably take care of it.

Comment: @matteoZanini i added the code